# How do I run my app using a local bundle rather than the dev server

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to run KIF tests against my react-native app, but it fails on CI because the dev server isn't running. Apparently it's supposed to fall back to the local bundle if it doesn't find a running dev server, but that doesn't seem to be working.

I'm using react-native 0.33 and xcode 8.0.

Answer (score 1):

first, make a bundle using "react-native bundle" command. now ,you get a main.jsbundle.

then, put main.jsbundle into your xcode project,add like a resource.

finally,make sure you use RCTBridge to init RCTRootView,implement delegate "sourceUrlForBridge".

```js
- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  
//  NSString *jsBundlePath = @"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true";
//  NSURL *jsBundleURL = [NSURL URLWithString:jsBundlePath];
  
  
  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"main" ofType:@"jsbundle"];
  NSURL *jsBundleURL = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
  
  return jsBundleURL;
}
```